# Does anyone know of an Accurev plugin for VS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, accurev

The [Borland plugin](http://community.microfocus.com/borland/managetrack/accurev/) does not support past VS 2013.   Is there anything else out there?  Maybe open source?

Answer (score 4):

Support for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 was added in the 2016.1 version of AccuRev Visual Studio Plug-in.